# google+ integration in my application

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and am creating an android application with Google+ integration and saw a tutorial and started to follow it, but Google has updated the Google+ integration since the tutorial. For example, in the tutorial you used to click the (GET CONFIGURATION FILE) button https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating, but now it's been updated to (CONFIGURE PROJECT). I tried that, but I'm getting a credentials.json file instead of google-service.json file.

What do I do with the credentials.json file?

Comment: Refer this https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: @AndroCoderHelper Pls check my screen shot,  https://snag.gy/qmgJI7.jpg, but now it's been updated to (CONFIGURE PROJECT). I tried that, but I'm getting a credentials.json file instead of google-service.json file. You can get more clarify : https://snag.gy/iU3o9D.jpg

Comment: @AndroCoderHelper Hope you understand my error.