# Android Studio: Google API cant find credentials.json

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-signin

Following this guide on android studio: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java?authuser=3

Don't know where to put "credentials.json" file. Tryied lots of places: App, Raw, Resources, ..., none works.

This is the line that crashes:

```
InputStream in = GoogleAPISample.class.getResourceAsStream("/credentials.json");
if (in == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + "/credentials.json");
}
```

And this is the error thrown:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json
     at com.xxx.yyy.googleapi.GoogleAPISample.getCredentials(GoogleAPISample.java:66)
     at com.xxx.yyy.googleapi.GoogleAPISample.doExcec(GoogleAPISample.java:90)
     at com.xxx.yyy.ActivityLogin.OnClick_Login(ActivityLogin.java:86)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any suggestions of where to place such file?

These questions did not help me:

- [Where to put credentials.json in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397347/where-to-put-credentials-json-in-android-studio)
- [google+ integration in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112752/google-integration-in-my-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Do you have a solution for this isssue?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in assets foler and create `InputStream' like

```
InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

Or like Google suggests:
create ressources Folder in project folder.

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

InputStream in = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

Comment: which file path? 
Absolute path or Content root path or Source root path?

Comment: not path, just file. CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = credentials.json